# 'if/elseif' and 'is_active_sidebar' statement in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have this code:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('lt') && is_active_sidebar('rt')) { ?>

  <div class="grid_6 eqh">

<?php } elseif ( !is_active_sidebar('lt') || !is_active_sidebar('rt')) { ?>

  <div class="grid_9 eqh">

<?php } elseif ( !is_active_sidebar('lt') && !is_active_sidebar('rt')) { ?>

  <div class="grid_12 eqh">

<?php }; ?>
```

It's part of a wordpress theme I'm developing. It's supposed to show different classes according to a sidebar being active or not. The response I get from wp if a sidebar is active is 1 and NULL if it isn't. It works if the 'lt' sidebar is active, but the 'rt' is not, it diplays the 'grid_9' div, if none of the sidebars is active, it displays the 'grid_12' div, but if the 'rt' sidebar is inactive and the 'lt' is active, it still displays the 'grid_6' div. If I remove the 1st if statement:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('lt') && is_active_sidebar('rt')) { ?>
```

it doesn't display any of the divs.

I've tried every combination that came to my mind, I've separated the:

```
<?php } elseif ( !is_active_sidebar('lt') || !is_active_sidebar('rt')) { ?>
```

statement in 2 different ones, tried separate if statements without 'elseif', tried with, 'AND' and 'OR' instead of '&&' and '||' and a whole bunch of other variations, but nothing worked.

If anyone can help me or at least pont me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

As per @one-trick-pony 's suggestion, code is now:

```
<?php
$ltActive = is_active_sidebar('lt');
$rtActive = is_active_sidebar('rt');

if($ltActive && $rtActive){
  $class = 'grid_6';

}elseif(!$ltActive && !$rtActive){
  $class = 'grid_12';

}else{
  $class = 'grid_9';      // <==
}
?>

<div class="<?php echo $class; ?> eqh">
```

The php code is working, but it seems there is a bug with the `is_active_sidebar()` function in WP, but they are ignoring my question on the WP support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put the return result in variables (it will speed up processing a little):

```
$ltActive = is_active_sidebar('lt');
$rtActive = is_active_sidebar('rt');
```

Now, the problem is in your 2nd condition - you're checking if any of the sidebars are inactive, and if one of them or both are, the 3rd condition will never be evaluated.

So:

```
(!$ltActive && !$rtActive)
```

must go before:

```
(!$ltActive || !$rtActive)
```

(last condition will not be necessary, you can just leave `else{...}`)

---

Ok here's the code:

```
if($ltActive && $rtActive){
  $class = 'class when both sidebars are active';

}else(!$ltActive && !$rtActive){
  $class = 'class when both sidebars are inactive';

}else{
  $class = 'class when only one of the sidebars is active (either one)';      
}

?>
<div class="<?= $class; ?>">
```

Comment: That was a syntax error in my code (missing `if`). Anyway the general idea is still valid. Did you check what `is_active_sidebar()` returns for both sidebars? In WP a sidebar is considered active if there are widgets assigned it. If these widgets output nothing, it's still seen as active

Comment: Yes, I did check. There is a conditional call to the rt sidebar right after this div and it's not there, which means the sidebar is inactive. Also I don't have any widgets in that sidebar. Also I echoed the `is_active_sidebar()` and it returns 1 if sidebar is active and nothing (`NULL`?) if inactive

Comment: Perhaps you're mixing up the classes. What classes should be printed in each of the three situations? Did you check in the HTML if they are present? [A quick test](http://3v4l.org/NmLHr).

Comment: 1st of all, I really appreciate your help! Now to your questions: class when both sidebars are active: `grid_6`, class when both sidebars are inactive: `grid_12` and class when only one of the sidebars is active (either one): `grid_9`. I've checked, double checked and triple checked every instance. [the site](http://kendallellis.co/energy-and-infrastructure/). You can see there is no right sidebar, still the class is `grid_6` instead of `grid_9`

Comment: ok, do a `var_dump($ltActive, $rtActive);` on that page. You should get `1, null`

Comment: I got `bool(true) bool(true)`. I don't know how this is possible, because the right sidebar (rt) is displayed using the same conditionals: `<?php if( is_active_sidebar('rt') ) : ?>

<div class="grid_3 right eqh">
    
<?php dynamic_sidebar('rt'); ?>

</div><!--grid_3-->

<?php endif; ?>`... I'm totally lost now

Comment: Maybe it's a bug with that function. Try posting this on WPSE or the WP support forums. PS: you could also try with [output buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781018/wordpress-widget-hide-if-empty/14781154#14781154) and check if there is any sidebar content, instead of relying on `is_active_sidebar()`...